# PHP is acting up, what's wrong? (re-declare error when including a file)

Tags: php, apache, centos, cpanel, whm

Well, when I declare a function in a file and vist the file from URL, there's no errors, but if the file is included in another file, I get a re-declare error, but it's never re-declared and I did not include the file more than once cause I'm using require_once()

Is there anything server wise I can do to fix this from reading the page 2x?

Running centos 6 64 bit with cPanel/WHS

Comment: Use `include_once` rather than `include` in your code

Comment: @MarkBaker they mentioned using `require_once()` already

Comment: I said in OP I'm not including the file more than once.

Comment: `but if the file is included in another file`: Can we see your file which includes this file? My guess is that your `another` file is also declaring that function which your included file already has declared.

Comment: Ahh, turns out there was a bug in one of my files causing this. Nothing to do with the server, thanks.